# Entity with EmbeddedId throw EntityNotFoundException when refreshing

Tags: jpa, glassfish, entity, eclipselink

I'm facing a weird issue : EntityNotFoundException keeps being thrown when I refresh an entity with embedded id.

The code :

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @EmbeddedId
    private APk pk;

    public A(int id, Date date) {
        pk = new APk(id, date);
    }

    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class APk {
    private int id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    ...
}
```

Then, in an EJB method :

```
A entity = new A(1, new Date());

em.persist(entity);
em.flush();
em.refresh(entity); -> here's where the exception is thrown
```

Stacktrace :

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Entity no longer exists in the database: [id=1, date=25-07-2013 15:02].
```

I'm using Glassfish v3.1.2 with Eclipse Link 2.4.2 as JPA provider (but it did the same with embedded provider).

Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type used for the date field in the database?  Try setting logging to finest to see the SQL and parameters used, and verify the same query works elsewhere.  I'm betting the type is truncated in the field so it can't match the date used in the query.  It should probably set the temporal type in the embeddable id that is a java.util.Date type http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Temporal

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The date field in database has type `datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-01-01 00:00:00'`. I'm using `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` on the java.util.Date type. I missed it on the sample above (but was in my class). I'm going to try logging finest and will keep you inform.